# Would this be an acceptable translation of the English statement as well?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, computer-science, predicate-logic, quantifiers

This is an except from my textbook (Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 7th Edition)
[image]

This was my initial stab at the problem [image]
(with domain of both variables being all real numbers)

Would it also be acceptable in my solution to introduce the y variable a bit earlier than the author's solution. What I was thinking was for every real number $x$, that exists a real number $y$ for which the implication will eventually be evaluated for. I understand what the author was getting at though, you don't really care about the $y$ unless you meet the first condition, then you can iterate the $y$s. Would my solution be acceptable as well? I believe they are logically equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Your solution is also acceptable. They are logically equivalent. You have just written your answer in [Prenex Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form). Furthermore, every sentence in FOL is logically equivalent to a sentence with the quantifiers at the beginning.

Comment: Yeah that wiki article was pretty overwhelming. Basically mines in prenex normal form because i included all the quantifiers in the beginning?

Comment: @committedandroider: Haha, that's correct. Many people (including myself) find this form to be the most natural.